# How would I go about making Pushboxes in a 2D fighting game?

Tags: c++, sdl2, fighting-game

I am working on a 2D fighting game engine in C++ and SDL2 and everything so far is going swimmingly. I have hitboxes, hurtboxes, and pushboxes as you would expect of a typical fighting game. How exactly would I make the pushboxes behave like they do in Street Fighter 3 or any other modern fighting game? By this I mean that if both people are pushing each other, nobody moves. If someone is moving and the other isn't, then the moving player pushes the idle player. So far I know that the system is more lax than correcting the position to be right outside of the other person's pushbox every frame, as there can be some overlap in SF3 and other games. I just don't know how to implement something like this and I haven't been able to find a satisfactory answer online. How should I go about implementing this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you quantity "some overlap" or the situations in which that overlap should be allowed to occur in your game? Right now, this question is somewhat under-specified, in that lots of different answers might fit the description in the text and still not be what you actually want.